# Simple jquery counter on appear

Tags: jquery, counter

There are so many different counter scripts I'm not sure where to start, what's overkill and what's not.

I'm looking for a simple counter script that fires when the target element first appears into view onscreen (for example, does not fire until scrolled into view)

The idea is that all I have to do to get the element to animate/count when scrolled into view, is give it a class of `counter`.

For example, html will be:

```
<span class="counter">99</span><span class="counter">55</span>
```

First, those elements would be set to `visibility:hidden` until scrolled into view. Then, they would increment from 0 to the value of the text node (99 and 55 in this case) and stop when they reach the value. Some sort of ease out effect may be desirable but isn't a must (for example, start fast and slow down as it reaches the value)

Thanks in advance. Just looking for the simplest solution.

Comment: there are lots of page scroll plugins, what have you tried?

Comment: Well you need to show an attempt, otherwise this looks like a `write some code for me` question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a complete code for your purpose:

```
function isElementVisible($elementToBeChecked)
{
    var TopView = $(window).scrollTop();
    var BotView = TopView + $(window).height();
    var TopElement = $elementToBeChecked.offset().top;
    var BotElement = TopElement + $elementToBeChecked.height();
    return ((BotElement <= BotView) && (TopElement >= TopView));
}

$(window).scroll(function () {
    $( ".counter" ).each(function() {
    isOnView = isElementVisible($(this));
        if(isOnView && !$(this).hasClass('Starting')){
           $(this).addClass('Starting');
           startTimer($(this));
        }
    });
});

function startTimer($this) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $this.html($this.html() - 1);
        startTimer($this);
    }, 1000); 
}
```

The `isElementVisible` function help to find out is a control is appeared on the screen after every scroll or not.

Then you call this function of every scroll and if  a `.counter` element appear on display, then start timer ONLY for THIS element using the `startTimer` function.

The `!$(this).hasClass('Starting')` is added to code to prevent unwanted call function, when a timer is started before and scroll on it again and again.
When a timer start for first time, the `Starting` class is added to element and is skipped in next times.

**>>> [JSFiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/TzLaD/1/)**

You can see that every timer start only when is seen and other counters don't start until those are seen too.

Comment: Moshaf, this gets me started. However, it counts backwards. How can I modify it to count from zero, up to the target number, then stop?

Comment: In the `startTimer` function you can check the $this.html() value and doing what you want easily.
You can set the defaults to zero and +1 instead of -1 and check `$this.html()` if reach to specific number, stop counting.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like part of your question already has an answer: [Start executing jQuery function when I scroll to a specific <div>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935762/start-executing-jquery-function-when-i-scroll-to-a-specific-div?lq=1)

The answer on that question has a jsfiddle that will get you started. It's a matter of writing a simple counter script in start_count