# jQuery when bottom of element is in screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, conditional-statements, jquery-waypoints

I have some jQuery that only needs to do something when the viewport hits the bottom of a specific element.

[image]

In this picture u can see 3 color sections. the blue one is what I see when I load my web page. The black one is where the jQuery applies. and I only want to initialize the black jQuery when the Red part is on the screen.

Is this possible? I am not very good with jQuery but I still tried some thing:

HTML:

```
<row class="teller-wrapper">  </row>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery('.teller-wrapper').waypoint(function(){

    console.log("ik ben nu in beeld, lopen met die tellers");

}, {offset: 'bottom-in-view'});
```

But the console log does not show when I scroll over the red part.

At this point I am trying with the Waypoints jQuery extension but I can't get it to work properly.

- *jQuery Waypoints - v2.0.2
- *Jquery - v1.11.2

I do not mind using something else than Waypoints extension so any suggestion is welcome. In the meantime ill just keep try and error with what I have now.

I hope someone has a solution

Thanks in advance and happy coding.

Comment: You want to implement like [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935762/start-executing-jquery-function-when-i-scroll-to-a-specific-div) ?

Comment: @Nimish Hmm yes something like that ill immediatly will take a look. i find it interesting that i didnt find this myself :O

Comment: If you have posted your HTML then i might have resolved your issue but you can follow the link and resolve yourself. It would be better as you will learn something

Comment: you can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)

Comment: @Nimish would like to learn this myself. but i placed the question here for a good push in the right direction what 3 ppl already did by now so im happy enough :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it with help of jquery scroll library

link : https://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Comment: i had dissabled scrolling trough CSS so i had to put it on the `body tag`